# What's the most efficient way to combine dates?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Records in my database look like this:

```
From: 2012-01-16 06:20:00   To: 2012-01-16 06:30:00
From: 2012-01-16 06:30:00   To: 2012-01-16 06:40:00
From: 2012-01-16 06:40:00   To: 2012-01-16 06:50:00
```

And inside my application I have to combine them into 1 record looking like this:

```
From: 2012-01-16 06:20:00   To: 2012-01-16 06:50:00
```

Sometimes records are not in any order. They might look like that:

```
From: 2012-01-16 06:20:00   To: 2012-01-16 06:30:00
From: 2012-01-16 06:40:00   To: 2012-01-16 06:50:00
From: 2012-01-16 06:30:00   To: 2012-01-16 06:40:00
```

Comment: this a Timestam()?, or a time selected?

Comment: it is a timestamp

Comment: then the order must be sorted

Comment: sorted and then combined? is there any other way?

Comment: please put your code, because now i got no idea.

Comment: If you could post how the records look when reaching client side it would help a lot

Comment: No idea what you mean when you say 'combine'. It's so vague! Do you mean add durations for a host of ranges?

Comment: He wants to combine the earliest from-date and the latest to-date.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a timestamp you may use MIN(from) and MAX(to).

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most efficient way, but I would do it like this:

```
let timeRanges = [];

timeRanges.push({
  from:  new Date(Date.parse('2012-01-16 06:20:00')),
  to: new Date(Date.parse('2012-01-16 06:30:00'))
});

timeRanges.push({
  from:  new Date(Date.parse('2012-01-16 06:40:00')),
  to: new Date(Date.parse('2012-01-16 06:50:00'))
});

timeRanges.push({
  from:  new Date(Date.parse('2012-01-16 06:30:00')),
  to: new Date(Date.parse('2012-01-16 06:40:00'))
});

let combinedTimeRange = {
  from: null,
  to: null
};

for(let timeRange of timeRanges) {
  if(combinedTimeRange.from === null 
    || combinedTimeRange.from.getTime() > timeRange.from.getTime()) {
      combinedTimeRange.from = timeRange.from;
  }

  if(combinedTimeRange.to === null 
    || combinedTimeRange.to.getTime() < timeRange.to.getTime()) {
      combinedTimeRange.to = timeRange.to;
  }
}

// just a test ..
console.log(combinedTimeRange.from.getMinutes());
console.log(combinedTimeRange.to.getMinutes());
```